# How to populate an field in array of Mongooese?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a collection schema like this:

```
const PrescriptionSchema = new Schema({
    patientId:{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    prescriptionName: String,
    prescriptionNote: String,
    prescriptionDate: Date,
    diseaseId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Diseases'},
    drugs: [{
        drugcateId:{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'DrugCategory'},
        quantity: Number,
        howtouse: String
    }],
    is_deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    createdBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
}, {
        timestamps: true,
        collection: 'prescriptions'
    }
);
export default mongoose.model('prescriptions', PrescriptionSchema );
```

Note that in this collection I have an array of "drugs", this is an array of drug that I get from 'DrugCategory', in each drug I have quantity and howtouse..so that I group it (drugCateId, quantity, howtouse) in drugs array.
When I find a prescription, I want to populate drugCateId inside drugs array. How can I do it?
Below is my current code:

```
async findOne(req, res){
        const { id } = req.params;
       await Prescriptions.
            findOne({ is_deleted: false, _id: id}).
             .populate(
               {
                 path: 'drugs',
                   populate: {
                     path: 'drugCateId',
                     model: 'DrugCategory'
                   }
               }).
            exec(function (err, data) {
              if (err) return handleError(err);
              res.send(data)
            });
      }
```

But it's not work.
Below is my result:

```
{
    "is_deleted": false,
    "_id": "5f32768a06693a520806717d",
    "patientId": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
    "prescriptionName": "Prescription for you",
    "prescriptionNote": "Please drink follow doctor",
    "prescriptionDate": "2020-07-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "diseaseId": "5f22a6d600980c081ca9e14f",
    "drugs": [
        {
            "_id": "5f32768a06693a5208067181",
            "drugcateId": "5f23deca04e3150a48632229", // How can I populate this one?
            "quantity": 10,
            "howtouse": "drink 2 times after meal everyday"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f32768a06693a5208067180",
            "drugcateId": "5f23deca04e3150a48632233", // How can I populate this one?
            "quantity": 10,
            "howtouse": "drink 2 times after meal everyday"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f32768a06693a520806717f",
            "drugcateId": "5f23deca04e3150a48632234", // How can I populate this one?
            "quantity": 10,
            "howtouse": "drink 2 times after meal everyday"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f32768a06693a520806717e",
            "drugcateId": "5f23deca04e3150a4863224a", // How can I populate this one?
            "quantity": 10,
            "howtouse": "drink 2 times after meal everyday"
        }
    ],
    "createdBy": "5d1cd947231ceb95b8838c1b",
    "createdAt": "2020-08-11T10:44:26.842Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-11T10:44:26.842Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I hope you understand my issue, please take a look. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current version does not match your schema. It suggest you want to populate both `drugs` and `drugs.drugcateId`. But here `drugs` are embedded directly and not references to documents in another collection, so it's not possible to `populate()`:

```
 .populate({
     path: 'drugs',  // this assumes drugs are objectIds: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Drug' }]
     populate: {
       path: 'drugCateId',
       model: 'DrugCategory'
     }
   })
```

Instead, you should be able to use dot-notation for arrays:

```
.populate({ path: "drugs.drugcateId" })
```

or short

```
.populate("drugs.drugcateId")
```

Comment: Yes, I haveThanks you for your reply. I have a mistake that my model is "drugcate" but in my populate command is "drugCate". I already change my model to "drugCate" and bellow query is worked. 
```
populate({ path: 'drugs.drugCateId', 
   populate: {path: 'drugs.drugCateId'}
}) 
```
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were very close it seems, but make sure to give the proper path:

```
.populate({
   path: 'drugcateId',
   model: 'DrugCategory'
})
```

Change `drugCateId` to `drugcateId`.

Also, you should be able to directly populate `DrugCategory`.

Comment: Yes, I have a misstake that my model is "drugcate" but in my populate command is "drugCate". I already change my model to "drugCate" and bellow query is worked.
populate({
              path: 'drugs.drugCateId', 
                populate: {path: 'drugs.drugCateId'}
            })
Thanks you

Comment: Yes, that is what I pointed out. I'm not sure why you nested population like this. Wouldn't the code from my answer be enough? Have you tried populating it that way - simply one direct populate?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your reply. I have a mistake that my model is "drugcate" but in my populate command is "drugCate". I already change my model to "drugCate" and bellow query is worked.

```
populate({ path: 'drugs.drugCateId', 
   populate: {path: 'drugs.drugCateId'}
})
```

Thanks